# What happens to the original data if i set a variable to null? c#

Tags: c#, object, variables, memory, null

I just wonder what would happen to the original data if i set its assigned variable to null?

For example:

```
class Fruits{
    public int Count;
    public List<string> Names;
}

class Main{
    private Fruits fruits = new fruits();

    void SetFruitsToNull(){
        this.fruits = null;//What happens to the original fruits variable's value? Does it get deleted?
    }

}
```

Comment: If an object no longer has any references to it, it will eventually be cleaned up by the garbage collector. Until then, it remains in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable in your precise example  is not longer referenced, so it can be collected by the Garbage Collector. I can guarantee you it will run - even on exceptions - but not **when** it will run. For most cases this is not a problem.

If you already copied the reference to another variable, it is simply no longer referenced under fruits - but still under any other variable you assigned it too. The GC can not work if at there is still a strong reference to the instance

If you have some unamanged resource that needs timely freeing (any Network or File Handles), that is what the IDisposeable pattern and using blocks are there for.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explains it! :)